# Using cardano-cli, is their any way to decode a plutus script which is in cbor?

Tags: cardano-cli, script, cbor, decode

I am using "cardano-cli text-view decode-cbor --in-file mint.plutus" which is just returning the cbor portion as a result.

Even tried saving an --out-file via: .json etc...But gives me Giberish when I "cat" it.

Any way to decode a plutus script in CLI instead of using an external source?

There is an existing post which talks about decoding "transactions" (which works for transactions), - but that does not work when I manipulate it with a plutus cbor script->
[How to decode cbor which is generated with cardano-cli build command?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/how-to-decode-cbor-which-is-generated-with-cardano-cli-build-command/4520#4520)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with cardano-cli. There are executables in [plutus](https://github.com/IntersectMBO/plutus) that you may find useful. See https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/11449/1071.